# Why fontawesome icons are not getting applied to gridview icons?

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, webforms, font-awesome

I am trying to apply Font-Awesome icon on Command Fields and it appears but I don't want the default text of command fields i.e. EDIT, Select, Delete etc and only icon to display. I tried my best but couldn't sort it out.

```
<asp:GridView ID="dgvEmployees" runat="server" CssClass="table table-borderless table-striped">
    <Columns>
        <asp:CommandField ButtonType="Link" ShowSelectButton="true" SelectText="View" />
        <asp:CommandField ButtonType="Link" ShowEditButton="true" ItemStyle-CssClass="fa fa-pencil" />
        <asp:CommandField ShowDeleteButton="true" />
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

Comment: The class is set to the `td`, not the hyperlink. You need to use TemplateField.

Answer (score 0):

In SelectText you can use this:

```
SelectText="<i class='glyphicon glyphicon-pencil'></i>"
```

or

```
SelectText="<i class='fa fa-pencil'></i>"
```